# How to read data in a named range?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I've been through the documentation of the Google Sheets API v4 and couldn't find a way to read data from a *named* range.
I'm using Python, specifically, and looking for something along the lines of:

```
named_range = 'My Beautiful Range'
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=my_id,
                            namedRange=named_range).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

Is there such an API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?hl=en) and [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?hl=en) accepts named ranges as their `range parameter`.

Just keep in mind that your named ranges should be valid and existing in the spreadsheet that you are trying to access.

### NOTE:

**[Valid Range Names:](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175)**

- Can contain only letters, numbers, and underscores.
- Can't start with a number, or the words "true" or "false."
- Can't contain any spaces or punctuation.
- Must be 1–250 characters.
- Can't be in either A1 or R1C1 syntax. For example, you might get an error if you give your range a name like "A1:B2" or "R1C1:R2C2."

---

**Sample Code:**

```
named_range = 'MyBeautifulRange'
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=my_id,
                            range=named_range).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
```

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**Sample [spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get?hl=en) request using API explorer:**

[image]

**Sample Response Body:**

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:B3",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "A1",
      "B1"
    ],
    [
      "A2",
      "B2"
    ],
    [
      "A3",
      "B3"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I saw OP's script and your sample script, I noticed an modification point. So how about the following modification? I think that when your sample script is run, an error occurs. Because there is no name of `namedRange`. In this case, please use `range` instead of `namedRange`. So it's like `modify result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=my_id, range=named_range).execute()`. I think that your answer has a lot of important information. So, by this modification, I think that your answer will be more useful for OP and other users.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I wasn't able to check the python library when I created the solution. I updated the answer based on your modification

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this to just work... The documentation clearly states:

_"range: The A1 notation of the values to retrieve."_

Thank you @Tanaike !

Comment: @Ron M Thank you for replying. I think that your answer will be useful for a lot of users.

Comment: @user2470305 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Tagged the wrong person, meant to thank @RonM as well :)